# Unable to connect to GraphQL API with fetch, getting CORS error

Tags: node.js, graphql, cors

I've been reading posts about CORS the last two days, and tried every?.. combination of tips, but still can't get this working.

I used Node and installed 'graphql', 'express' and 'express-graphql'.

The GraphiQL GUI page works fine. Server running at :6969

Then I have a web-server that I also installed with Node for my front-end running at :8000
It's installed globally with -g. I'd be amazed it matters thought. And when I try to make requests to the API I get this error in my browser:

> Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:6969/graphql' from origin
> 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Why am I getting CORS errors when they have the same origin? Because they are listed at different ports?

I have tried installing an configuring 'cors' in my GraphQL-server. It didn't change anything.
I have tried modifying my request using:

```
mode: 'no-cors'
```

which only give me: 400 Bad request. I believe an opaque response is not what I want anyway.
And I have tried adding these to my request.

```
mode: 'cors'
credentials: 'include',
```

I have also tried modifying the header. This is the different headers I have tried:

```
let headers = new Headers()
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json')
headers.append('Origin',' http://127.0.0.1:6969/graphql')
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:6969/graphql')
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
```

I have also tried accessing from different IP's but I still can't escape this error.
I just don't understand where the "crossing" is supposed to be?

Here is the rest of my request:

...

```
fetch(' http://127.0.0.1:6969/graphql', {
        // mode: 'cors',
        // mode: 'no-cors',
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        // headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
    })
    .then(res => {
        if (res.status !== 200 && res.status !== 201) {
            throw new Error('Failed HTTP request!')
        }
        return res.json()
    })
    .then(resData => {
        window.thisDiv.innerHTML = resData.data
    })
    .catch(err => {
        window.thisDiv.innerHTML = `Server error! ${err}`
    })
}
```

Comment: The port is included in the same domain policy. Different ports trigger CORS. You're likely not setting `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'` on the actual graphql response header you're sending back. You should can verify this by looking at the headers in the chrome network tab for the options preflight query. You don't show us where you actually use the `headers` code.

Comment: if you include credentials, you cannot use '*' as allow origin

Comment: @AndyRay ohh, ok, so the port is. Well it's impossible to use the same port so...

I tried setting "allow *" in the response too, I will check the network tab to verify if it's actually working, thanks for the tip.

The headers code is applied in the code at the end, where you see "headers: headers,"

Comment: @StevenSpungin, ok, useful to know, I don't even know what the credentials are for, but the error persists either or which one I omit.

Comment: if you want to sent credentials to a different origin, both the server and the client must enable that option, and as a result the wildcard origin becomes restricted as a security measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better solution now.

The cors-package I installed was never used because I applied the cors code after I started the server. I just needed to swap those app.use() statements and it worked.

```
//...
const cors = require('cors')
const corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    accessControlAllowOrigin: '*',
    accessControlAllowCredentials: true,
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    graphiql: true
}))
```

Answer (score -3):

I found a temporary solution by Aditya Patnaik in a thread about CORS and localhost.

Just Run this line:

### Disable web security and site isolation trials in Chrome

```
chrome.exe  --disable-site-isolation-trials --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="PATH_TO_PROJECT_DIRECTORY"
```

PS: chrome added around 800 files and 300 folder to my directory. I'm still looking for a simpler solution where I only change the appropriate header or make the cors package work.